# Determining sufficiency of concentrated solutions

Tags: summation, chemistry

I am trying to make a function to calculate whether a given supply of reagents is sufficient to create a list of products at a given solution.

So for a list of products
$$
(a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2) ... (a_n, b_n) 
$$
where $a_n$ = concentration of solution (mol/L)

and $b_n$ = volume of solution (L)

and a list of supplies of the same format (concentration, volume)

How can I mathematically determine whether or not the supplies are sufficient to meet the demand, assuming I have infinite water to perform dilutions? Essentially, I'm trying to determine if I can create the "products" through any combination of dilutions of the finite and available supplies.

Dilution: If I have 500 L of a 2 mol/L solution, I can add 500 L of water to create 1000 L of a 1 mol/L solution. Thus, even a small amount of a very concentrated supply may satisfy many products.

Assumptions: Assume that for this situation, there is only one chemical at issue, and any "supply" can be used to satisfy any "product" . Heuristic solutions are usable if the % error is small (~ 5%). A product may also use many supplies, so long as the total volume of supply used is less than b. These lists are finite, but may contain thousands of items.

Attempts: I can think of a recursive way to perform this calculation, but it is computatioanlly expensive for a number of reasons related to the way this data is stored.

Comment: You should be able to convert to the number of moles and compare against the amount you have. That is, $\sum_{i} a_{i}b_{i} \leq n_{tot}$

Comment: @Zhe: If I have 300 quadrillion liters of a 0.00000000001 molar solution, I can never make 1 L of 1M solution, but I will have far more than 1 mol available. I can only dilute, not concentrate.

Comment: But you know that immediately... Am I missing an edge case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the lists of products and supplies so that the most concentrated solutions appear first.

Start on the first product solution (the most concentrated). If the first supply solution is less concentrated, give up, you can't win. Otherwise, calculate how much of the first supply solution you need to create this product. If you have enough to fill it, then subtract the needed amount and continue on to the next product solution. If not, then subtract the amount you could fill from the product amount, and move on the the next supply solution as needed.

If at some point your supply solution is less concentrated than the product solution, or if you run out of supply solutions when you still have product, there is no way to do it. Otherwise you have constructed a way to meet the demand.

[Proof of above claim: Suppose at some point in this algorithm, the supply solution is less concentrated than the product solution. Call the product solution concentration C. Then split the products into those at lower concentration than C, and those at equal or higher concentration than C. Call the second set X. In order to meet the demand for X, we need an amount of supply with concentration $\geq C$ at least equal to the total amount of chemical ($\sum_{i\in X} a_i b_i) $ in the product. But by the construction of the algorithm, we used all the supply solution that met this constraint, and it still wasn't enough. The rest of the claims seem clear enough]

Comment: That's the recursive solution I was talking about, the problem is that sorting an array is a big performance bottleneck, and this calculation could occur thousands of times in a short space. Thanks for that concentration check idea though, that is a quick exit out. I'm trying to find a way to see if I can do the experiment before I do it. This is basically doing the experiment and seeing if it fails.

Comment: Sorting an array can be done in $O(n\log{n})$ time. (See quicksort or mergesort). Since there is clearly no way to avoid at least a linear time problem (reading in the data is linear time), this isn't a big performance issue.

Comment: I guess I was thinking about the worst case scenario for the sort. I'll implement it and see if that works.

Comment: If you are really concerned about worst case, use merge sort, but if you know ahead of time worst case is likely, you should be able to sort those cases very quickly since there is an obvious pattern to the worst case (which is a different pattern depending on how you choose the pivot). Also, the first thing you should try is to use an existing sort method in your language (e.g. sorted in python or std::sort in C++) to save a lot of time

Comment: Well I'm in Javascript, so I'm quite concerned with how fast the user sees results of things. I think `Array.sort()` uses Merge-sort.

Comment: Actually, I just had a brainstorm. What if I made a graph where Y is mols/L and X is liters? I add all As and all Bs, then compute the "area" of the triangle that produces, then do the same for supplies. if total Y is greater than the total Y for the products, and the area is greater than or equal to the area its possible. Can you see any edge cses?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I don't think it will work. The number of moles of a solution would be the area of the rectangle whose opposite corners are the origin and (A,B) on that graph, I don't see what triangle you are talking about. The total area comparison won't be enough for the reason you gave in your comment to Zhe. For each product, you need to know how much supply is 'higher' on this graph. But that basically boils down to sorting again.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I think I have a good median solution, sum the moles of the products, then loop over the supplies in a while loop until either the total volume exceeds or equals the total volume of the products, or the concentration of the supply is lower than the max of the products. When the loop breaks, the total mols of "supply" at that point are calculated, and if they are greater than or equal to the total mols of product, it is doable